# How to send document to apps script kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-apps-script

Currently Iam sending string and image file as string. to sheet via Apps script (sheet extension). Now I need to send a document files like (.zip, .glb, .obj, .arp, etc) I need to send these type of files to google sheet. so now I need to make user selected files as .zip. so now I need to send that .zip file to google sheet. but I couldnt do that.

```
private fun startUploading() {
        try {
            val map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()

            map["instagramLink"] = binding.creatorInstaID.text.toString()
            map["tutorialLink"] = binding.youTubeLink.text.toString() 
            map["detailDescription"] = binding.detailDescription.text.toString()
            map["coverImage"] = userImage!!

            mainViewModel.saveProduct(map)

        }

        catch (e:Exception){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Fill all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

Here userImage is the user selected image which is converted as string.
other values are string values it can be sent to google sheet easily.
now how can i send a custom file types to google sheet. as like this.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found is converting the encode the file to [base64](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata). Then add the string of base64 to the Google Sheet. I made a sample file with a Zip file store in Google Drive. You might need to adjust the code as needed.

Also, remember that character limit of a Google Cell is [50,000](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en#:%7E:text=with%20more%20than-,50%2C000%20characters,-will%20be%20removed), so I added an `if` statement in case the encode file has more than  50,000 characters and split the string in an array of 45000 characters.

*Note: The same sample code can be use on any type of files.*

```
function encode64() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  // get the file from Google Drive using the ID
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById("Drive_Zip_File_ID");

  //convert the zip file to blob
  let file_in_blop = file.getBlob();

  //convert the blop to bytes
  let file_in_bytes = file_in_blop.getBytes();

  //encode the bytes to base64
  let encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(file_in_bytes);

  //get the length of charactes from the base 64 encode
  let length_string = encoded.length

  //split the string to array in chunks less than 45000 characters
  if (length_string > 50000){
    const result = encoded.match(/.{1,45000}/g) ?? [];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(result[i]); 
    }
  }else(sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(result)); 
}
```